# ListCollectionView EditItem/CommitEdit causes bad current item (selection) behavior

Tags: wpf

I use EditItem/CommitEdit for resorting (grouped) collection when some property of any item has changed. I do not want to call Refresh() because the collection contains a lot of items with relatively complicated visual tree so it slows down the application.

I faced some strange behavior when calling CommitEdit for current (selected) item - it will lost its currency during the process, of course I can still set it back through MoveCurrentTo(item) so everything looks fine at the moment. But... When for example a new item is added to the collection, the current item will automatically change with no reason to an item on the same index as was the edited item before the collection changed (added item) - it does not normally happen without calling CommitEdit in past.

I use master/detail model so properly set current item is very important for me. Did anyone went around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was digging around it, debugging ListCollectionView and found there a bug (in my opinion). When a CommitEdit is called for any item, the item needs to be removed from collection and again added into it so the item can lost its currency during the process - thats expected. But there is a special case when edit a current item, some private field called _currentElementWasRemoved is set to true. When the collection will change next time (add, remove...) it looks into this field and change the current item, but in that time the current item should have already changed (I can call f.e MoveCurrentTo multiple times meantime) so this behavior is completely useless in my eyes.

So the walk around can be following: before calling the Edit/Commit for current item, move current pointer into another item or "deselect all" via MoveCurrentTo(null). Right after the CommitEdit was called you can simply return the pointer to the origin item by calling MoveCurrentTo(item).